# What does the notation $(\frac12)^3_n$ mean??

Tags: notation

Equation 97 in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PiFormulas.html introduces this notation I have never seen before:

$\left(\displaystyle\frac12\right)^3_n$

Everyone knows that 3 is an exponent, but what the heck is the $n$ doing down there???

I've tried googling this but I have no clue what to google.  The source of these formulas cost $$$.

Comment: [http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PochhammerSymbol.html)